# What is the weird wiring on these old light switches?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, receptacle, socket

Bedroom light switch, two of them but only on works to turn on the lights. There is a socket below it, and it gets it's power wires from this light switch box. The socket below has green and blue wires. There is no consistent color.

[image]

Comment: What part of the world is this in?

Comment: JUST A GUESS. since the yellow jumper wire is between two green wires i would think that the green is constant power and the red are the common wires. I do not see the blue wire making any connection in the box, just passes through. Disclaimer: i am not an electrician-er, i just play one one the internet. Please seek professional advice.

Comment: Those strands sticking out the side are a little terrifying, especially since that looks like an ungrounded metal box...

Comment: Can you provide us a photo that shows where the wires exit the back of the box?

Comment: @Hari Ganti I think the strands are insulation not wires. I would guess this is in the U.K.? But I have seen all green wiring in 1950's school buildings. But the lugs don't look like U.L. types I have ever used in the U.S.

Comment: @EdBeal I hope you're right!

Answer (score 1):

Without putting a meter on it. Yellow wire is a jumper to share power. The feed into the switch looks like one of the green wires but I cannot tell u which one is coming in and which one would be going out. Each of the reds look like your switched legs that are going to two separate lighting situations.

Answer (score 0):

Switches looks like BTicino Magic, green looks like a common (passing trough), reds like 'controlled' loads.